# Firefox only: left/right arrows move the entire page

Tags: html, css, firefox, web

This is a bizarre issue happening with my website on Firefox only. Using mouse scroll, I can only move up and down. That's the intended behavior. However, if I use arrows I can move the entire page to the right in what seems like ~40px increments. This creates a block of white space along the right edge of the browser window. I can also move it back to the left until the page is in the correct position (but no further -- ie, I can't create a white block on the left).

I don't want the left and right arrows to move the page like this... it happens to all of my site's pages (even the ones that are absolutely positioned). It only happens in Firefox (49.0.1).

Does anyone have any clues for me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I had put an `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` element to handle any horizontal overflow from the body. It turns out that this doesn't work the same way in Firefox as it does other browsers. In Firefox, it won't heed horizontal scrolling via arrow keys.

To better address the issue, consider first finding the offending element. As @JordanBarber mentions above, you can add `* { border: 1px solid red;}` to your CSS to see which element may be overflowing. You can also try Chris Coyier's recommendation here

https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

For my case, neither one of those techniques turned up any offending elements. I was able to solve my issue by moving the `overflow: hidden` from the `body` element to my `.header` element. I'll continue investigating the elements within the header to see why it's troublesome, but in the meantime, removing the `overflow-x: hidden` from `body` and adding it to `.header` fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the chrome dev tools (CMD + Shift + C) or you can do this in the Firefox inspector as well.  Make sure you are on the 'Elements' tab.  In the window on the right side (the CSS window), make sure the 'styles' tab is selected.  Click the small 'plus' symbol to add a new style declaration.  An automatic target will be added to a new css declaration, remove this target and target everything on the page by changing it to *.  Add this css rule: border: 1px solid red, making your added rule look like:

```
    * {
      border: 1px solid red;
   }
```

This will add a 1px red border to all elements on the page. Leave the dev tools open and move your page over with your arrows. Whatever is causing the overflow issue will be the element that has a red border extending across your excess whitespace. Hover over elements in the 'elements' tab to see what is causing the issue. You will then need to adjust the css of that element to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jordan. I'd done that, and did it again just now (just to make sure). I also tried the JS snippet Chris recommends on css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/ -- neither worked. I was able to isolate it to the header, and putting overflow-x on that solves it. I'll elaborate in my answer below